# How 4<<1<<2 is 32?

Tags: bit-manipulation

when

1<<2 : 4

4<<1<<2 should be 4<<4 which is 64

but it is showing 32.

I am new to bit manipulation, please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: research on precedence of operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is evaluated from left to right.

```
4 << 1 << 2
```

is equivalent to

```
(4 << 1) << 2
```

which is the same as

```
8 << 2
```

which equals

```
32
```